# I want to change the version of the framework.[swift4/xcode9]

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10, ios11, swift4

Currently I am migrating applications created with xcode 8 / swift 3 to xcode 9 / swift 4.

When I build and test on the actual machine without coding error.
It will fall in the middle of launching the application.
The real machine is iPhone 7's iOS 10.1.

■Error_message:
[image]

■Consideration:
In xcode I set it to find a library for iOS 11, but I think that there is no library for iOS 11 in iPhone 7.

I think that updating iPhone 7 from iOS 10.1 to iOS 11 will start the application without problems.

However, since I want users to enjoy the application from iOS 10.1 to iOS 11, I would like to use a library for iOS 10.1 instead of a library for iOS 11.

When converting from swift 3 to swift 4 automatically, (I do not know the timing)
I think that xcode has been set to automatically search for iOS 11 libraries.

■Questions:
How should I use the library for iOS 10.1?
Or, for example.
Can I allow iOS 11 users to apply libraries for iOS 11 and iOS 10 users to apply iOS 10 libraries?

[image]

[image]

■Supplementary information.
xcode9/swift4
iPhone7/iOS10.1
DeploymentTarget:10.1

I changed the setting from "On" to "Default" 
because the following error was displayed when I moved swift 4.
error_massage:
The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the application launched when I performed "clean".